# The final scene in Joker

Tags: ending, joker

Most interpretations I've found online, including a few on this site, seem to believe that the events of Joker are all imagined, and the only "real" scene is the final scene, with Joker in Arkham Asylum.

If this is the case, can someone explain why, when the camera pans past the face of the social worker who is questioning him in the final scene, we see Arthur standing in the shadows behind her?  It's like he's an observer, which makes the scene feel like it's imagined as well.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the end scene wants to point out the fact that Arthur was in the Asylum for a long time and hence the doctor looks so aged from before, and he kills her in the end(remember the bloody foot prints). 
From the suicide squad we know that Joker met Harley Quinn who was a former doctor in the asylum, and helped him escape cause we see that the guards come chasing after him  and he runs from one end to another without knowing where to go.

Comment: @war_Hero: Do we know that _Joker_ and _Sucide Squad_ belong to the same continuity?

Comment: @DaG No they definitely don't. This Joker exists way in the past when Bruce Wayne was only a kid.

Comment: @DaG: Regardless of specific continuity, some things carry over inbetween. Commonly, how Bruce's parents die in the alley (though the killer sometimes changes), and Harley's origin story also doesn't really change inbetween continuities.